# How to make a CSS button work correctly?

Tags: html, css

I've created a CSS box to replace the floating (sliding) sidebar image .jpg banner on my site which is hosted on blogger. But, the CSS button is not working correctly as it should work.

**Actual code created [Working correctly]:**

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
div {
    background-color: white;
    width: 300px;
    border: 3px solid #008CBA;
    padding: 25px;
    font-size: 35px;
    margin: 25px;
}
.button {
    background-color: #008CBA; 
    border-radius: 6px;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px 10px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin: 4px 2px;
    width: 180px;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s; 
    transition-duration: 0.4s;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.button {
    background-color: #008CBA;
    color: white;
    border: 2px solid #008CBA;

}
.button:hover {
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    border: 2px solid #008CBA;
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div><center><font color="red">Earn Upto $500 per month !!!!</font>
<br />
<p style="font-size:20px">Best sites in the world that pay up to $10 per study.</p>

<a class="button" href="http://www.genuineonlinefreejobs.com/2015/04/top-10-genuine-paid-online-jobs-survey-panels.html" target="_blank" title="Click here to start making money - No Registration fees!!!">LEARN MORE</a>

<br />
<p style="font-size:8px">* Opportunities & earnings will vary depending on your  Geo location</p>
</center>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Code edited to work on blogger: [CSS button appear like a link]**

```
<div id='genuinesurvey'>
<style>
.box {
    background-color: white;
    width: 250px;
    border: 3px solid #008CBA;
    padding: 25px;
    font-size: 35px;
    margin: 25px;
}
.button {
    background-color: #008CBA; 
    border-radius: 6px;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px 10px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin: 4px 2px;
    width: 180px;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s; 
    transition-duration: 0.4s;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.button {
    background-color: #008CBA;
    font-color: white;
    border: 2px solid #008CBA;
}
.button:hover {
    background-color: white;
    font-color: black;
    border: 2px solid #008CBA;
}
</style>
<div class="box"><center><font color="red">Earn Upto $500 per month !!!!</font>
<br />
<p style="font-size:20px">Best sites in the world that pay up to $10 per study.</p>

<div class="button"><a href="http://www.genuineonlinefreejobs.com/2015/04/top-10-genuine-paid-online-jobs-survey-panels.html" target="_blank" title="Click here to start making money - No Registration fees!!!">LEARN MORE</a></div>
<br />
<p style="font-size:8px">* Opportunities & earnings will vary depending on your Geo location.</p>
</center>
</div>
<style>
#genuinesurvey {
   position: relative;
}
</style>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I tested the two excerpts of code out the only thing I could tell was different was the text inside the button, that said you should really clarify more then saying your button is not working right. To fix the text issue just add this to your code:

```
a {
  text-decoration:none;
  color:white;
}
a:hover {
  color:black;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, thank you. You're right, I mean button is working correctly but text inside it is not working properly. I've added the code you've said in css section. The underline only disappeared but the color remains the same like a link. When I hover the white doesn't change to black. Instead it remain blue color all the time.

Comment: Just edited the code in my post, let me know if that works

Comment: Thanks. Its works perfectly when I checked it. But when I added it to my site it still doesn't work well. The font don't appear in white and also when hovered the underlineline appearing like the link. Please take a look at my site, I've added it to my site. Please tell me a solution to make it appear correct if you can.

Comment: adding text-decoration:none to the a:hover in css should get the underline away permanently. For the color change, I don't know why it is just grey when it is on your website so I can't help you with that, sorry

Comment: Thank you @Joshua for support. I will find a solution for it.

Comment: Thanks and sorry I couldn't help further.